# Measuring delay with audio fingerprinting (Java)

Tags: java, audio, fingerprinting

I would like to measure the delay between one live stream on two different platforms using audio fingerprinting. Currently I am using musicg library for Java. I can obtain information such as the spectrogram and the fingerprints but I couldn't figure out how to use the data for measuring the delay.

My question is whether the musicg library is enough for this kind of operation. If so, how can I use the data I've acquired to find the delay between the two streams.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do.  I would create 2 `HashMap<FingerprintData, Long>`s.  Essentially you are mapping fingerprint data from your streams to a reply from `System.nanoTime()`.

I would then create a "game-loop" that runs "forever", or until you don't want it to anymore, and each iteration I would take the fingerprint data from each stream and and check if either `HashMap.keySet().contains(theFingerPrintData)` from the opposite stream.  If it does, you'll release it from the `HashMap` and do the math to find the delay like so:

Also, I'm not sure what your class is used for your fingerprint data, so for my example I will just call it `FingerprintData`

```
Map<FingerprintData, Long> stream1Timestamps = new HashMap<>();
Map<FingerprintData, Long> stream2Timestamps = new HashMap<>();

StreamClass stream1 = howEverYouFetchStream(1);
StreamClass stream2 = howEverYouFetchStream(2);

while(true /*or if you have conditional to terminate place it here*/){
     FingerprintData stream1fpd = stream1.getFingerprintData();
     FingerprintData stream2fpd = stream2.getFingerprintData();

     if(stream1Timestamps.keySet().contains(stream2fpd)){
         Long firstHeard = stream1Timestamps.get(stream2fpd);
         System.out.println("stream 2 is delayed:" +System.nanoTime()-firstHeard + " nanoseconds");
         stream1Timestamps.remove(stream2fpd);
     }else{
         stream2Timestamps.put(stream2fpd, System.nanoTime();
     }

     if(stream2Timestamps.keySet().contains(stream1fpd)){
         Long firstHeard = stream2Timestamps.get(stream1fpd);
         System.out.println("stream 1 is delayed:" +System.nanoTime()-firstHeard + " nanoseconds");
         stream2Timestamps.remove(stream1fpd);
     }else{
         stream1Timestamps.put(stream1fpd, System.nanoTime();
     }

  }
```

This may need to be tweaked a little bit, but essentially I believe this is what you are looking for.